# Performing function on array with try and except in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, try-except

I'm trying to run a function on each row in a dataframe that sometimes throws errors at me. I'm trying to avoid using iterations but when I use try-except as soon as the function breaks it gets stuck performing the execution in 'except'.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delimiter = "\t")

try: 
     df['col_b'] = function(df['col_a'].to_csv('out.txt', header=True, sep='\t)
except:
     df['col_b'] = 'This is an Error'
```

So where the first few rows in col_a will output whatever function() returns, as soon as function() throws an error every row after will be 'This is an error'.

Is there a way I can return to 'try'?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote after `'\t`

Comment: The code in the `except` block doesn't apply to just the row where it got an error. It's assigning to the entire column.

Comment: I think you need to use an ordinary loop so you can put the `try/catch` within the loop and only operate on the current row.

Comment: `df['col_a']` is a `Series`.  `to_csv` with a filename like that returns none.  I don't see the point in giving that as a argument to `function`.